# Rewrite numbers to default page

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a condition that can take any page that has numbers.html, lets say the like the following:

```
12345.html
33443.html
234545656.html
9797423.html
```

and just redirect it to index.php

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php [L]
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two immediate issues with your code:

1. you have to switch on the rewriting engine prior to using it and
2. if you want to match file names ending with `.html`, then you have to code that.

Have a try with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php [L]
```

Then a few more hints:

- the code you tried will only work in `.htaccess` style files. But the usage of such files has to be enabled first in your http server configuration.
- a `.htaccess` style file has to be placed at the correct location, in this example *within* the folder actually holding the `index.php` file.
- the rewriting module has to be installed and enabled, without those commands will not be available.

And a general remark:

Those `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow down the http server, often for nothing. You should *always* prefer to place such commands inside the real host configuration of your http server. `.htaccess` style files are only offered as a last option for situations where you have no access to that configuration, for example when using a really cheap shared hosting provider.

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what i was looking for